# Connect source from Assembla to GitHub

Tags: github, assembla

I am using Assembla (using git) for my project (including source code submissions).  The project owner would like the resulting source code saved in his github account.  How can I connect my Assembla submissions to github?  I can only find posts asking the other way around.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I work for Assembla - we are about to release a feature (no ETA right now) that allows you to run server-side hooks - this could be utilized.

We also have the SSH tool that would allow you to run arbitrary code on a server, that could check out and push up to github.

But if you want to do it manually, you can add a remote to your local repository for github and just push up to it:

```
git clone git@git.assembla.com:REPO.git
git add remote github git@github.com:user/REPO.git
git push github master
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Michael and @timjeep, I tried this manually, but it didn't work. After a few tries, I realized that with

```
git clone git@git.assembla.com:REPO.git
git remote add github git@github.com:user/REPO.git
git push github master
```

it worked. Just change the order for 'add' and 'remote' that it should work.

Answer (score 0):

@timjeep I'm currently working at Assembla. We released a connector tool to sync your github repo with an assembla one. Here is a link in case you are interested http://blog.assembla.com/why-you-need-application-connectors